# Why natural sorting required on Hashset before performing sorting based on any specific field, java8?

Tags: sorting, java-8, stream, set

I have seen a code to sort Hashset using java8 by any specific field.
In that sorting, first they are performing the natural sorting on object by implementing comparable interface, then they are performing sorting based on a specific field.

Query: Why should we perform natural sorting before specific field based sorting for set interface

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe the code you saw is wrong or you aren't been clear enough with your explanation. Sorting by one criteria first is not needed to sort by another criteria later. So, at first, it's not needed

Comment: "seen a code" - why not that put that code or a code snippet here, which improve the question. right now, this is a very open ended and not suitable for the community. try and make it more focused.

Answer (score 0):

Since the sorting algorithm provided by the JDK are in-place algorithms, you also want to sort those elements which results in `compare(o1, o2) == 0`.

You can achieve this by either sort the inital list via natural sort and then perform the sort based on the property or you could provide a `Comparator` combining these two sorting criterias (i.e. `Comparator#thenComparing`).

A simple and stupid example but should give you the idea

```
Comparator<Integer> tenthCompare = Comparator.comparing(i -> (i / 10) % 10);
Comparator<Integer> combinedCompare = tenthCompare.thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());

List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(5, 3, 1, 15, 13, 11, 25, 23, 21);

// Natural sort + property sort
System.out.println(numbers.stream().sorted().sorted(tenthCompare).collect(Collectors.toList()));
// [1, 3, 5, 11, 13, 15, 21, 23, 25]

// Property sort
System.out.println(numbers.stream().sorted(tenthCompare).collect(Collectors.toList()));
// [5, 3, 1, 15, 13, 11, 25, 23, 21]

// Combined sort    
System.out.println(numbers.stream().sorted(combinedCompare).collect(Collectors.toList()));
// [1, 3, 5, 11, 13, 15, 21, 23, 25]
```